# Verify that a sequence of dates are in the right order

Tags: r, date, sequence

I have a data frame that has 4 columns of dates.  It should be that col1 occurs first, col2 occurs second, col3 third, and col4 last.  Id like to identify which rows have dates that are not in sequence

Here is a toy data frame

```
col1 <- c(as.Date("2004-1-1"), as.Date("2005-1-1"), as.Date("2006-1-1"))
col2 <- c(as.Date("2004-1-2"), as.Date("2005-1-3"), as.Date("2006-1-2"))
col3 <- c(as.Date("2004-1-5"), as.Date("2005-1-9"), as.Date("2006-1-19"))
col4 <- c(as.Date("2004-1-9"), as.Date("2005-1-15"), as.Date("2006-1-10"))
dates <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3, col4)

dates

    col1       col2       col3       col4
1 2004-01-01 2004-01-02 2004-01-05 2004-01-09
2 2005-01-01 2005-01-03 2005-01-09 2005-01-15
3 2006-01-01 2006-01-02 2006-01-19 2006-01-10
```

My desired output would be,

```
    col1       col2       col3       col4       Seq?
1 2004-01-01 2004-01-02 2004-01-05 2004-01-09    T
2 2005-01-01 2005-01-03 2005-01-09 2005-01-15    T
3 2006-01-01 2006-01-02 2006-01-19 2006-01-10    F
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple `apply` statement will do the trick:

```
dates$Seq <- apply(dates, 1, function(x) all(x == sort(x)))
```

Answer (score 6):

I can think of a couple of solutions. Naively i'd suggest using `apply` with `?is.unsorted`, which is:

> Test if an object is not sorted (in increasing order), without the
>   cost of sorting it.

```
!apply(dates, 1, is.unsorted)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Otherwise, convert to a long set and then do a group operation, which should be faster on larger datasets:

```
tmp <- cbind(row=seq_len(nrow(dates)), stack(lapply(dates, as.vector)))
!tapply(tmp$values, tmp$row, FUN=is.unsorted)
```

And finally, the brute force method of comparing each column with the next via `Map`, which should be even quicker again:

```
Reduce(`&`, Map(`<`, dates[-length(dates)], dates[-1]))
```

Comment: For the last one, maybe `do.call(pmin, Map(\`<\`, dates[-length(dates)], dates[-1]))` would be slightly faster

Comment: @d.b - looks about the same by my timings. It also coerces the result to `c(1,1,0)` instead of the logical values.

Answer (score 2):

```
rowSums(Reduce(pmax, dates, accumulate = TRUE) == dates) == NCOL(dates)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

`Reduce` with `pmax` identifies the successive maximum date for each row. With `accumulate = TRUE` we preserve the output of `Reduce` for each iteration and compare with the original data in `dates`

Another approach that introduces `NA` if the dates are not sorted.

```
!is.na(Reduce(function(x, y) ifelse(x > y | is.na(x), NA, y), dates))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```