# In R, how to make sure values across some columns of dataframe always decreasing?

Tags: r

Could you please tell me what's wrong with my code?

I have data like so, and I need to check that the values across columns yr1, yr2 and yr3 are all constantly decreasing (or equal) in my data frame, and mark those that are not (e.g. product 1). But there's something wrong with my code.

````
check <- data.frame(type = c("product 1","product 2","product 3"), yr1 = c(10, 5, 0), yr2 = c(15, 3, 0), yr3 = c(10, 2, 0), yr4 = c(7, 2, 0), yr5 = c(1, 1, 0))



check$TLS_error<- ""
for (i in 1:nrow(check)){
#  starts with base_rate ends with second to least year
for(j in 2:ncol(check)-2){
  if(check[i,j]<check[i,j+1]){
  check$TLS_error[i]<-1
    }
   next
     }
   }

check %>%
filter(check$TLS_error==1)```
````

Comment: Useful stuff at this previous question potentially - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55347311/verify-that-a-sequence-of-dates-are-in-the-right-order/55347411

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion using a custom function and `apply`:

```
# function that checks if values in a row are decreasing from left to right
my_func <- function(row) {
  all(diff(row) <= 0)
}

check$TLS_error <- as.integer(apply(check[-1], 1, my_func))
check
```

```
       col1 yr1 yr2 yr3 TLS_error
1 product 1  10  15  10         0
2 product 2   5   3   2         1
3 product 3   0   0   1         0
```